# How to test a API with rspec and capybara on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec, capybara

I have created a controller that can read api data by a special url.

```
def category
  @data = get_api_data(param1)
end

def get_api_data(param1)
  "http://my_api_url/param1=#{param1}"
end
```

After I create a view, I can see the result from browser.

If I use rspec + capybara to do the feature test

```
visit category_path('param1')
```

Then I want to confirm a api data will be shown in view

```
expect(page).to have_field('name', with: 'aaa')
```

But the `@data` value always be null. Why? Is it necessary to do a api url access post from test code? If it is necessary, how to do? The `visit` method can't take other params.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capybara is not designed for testing APIs. You should go with Rspec and Airbone: https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to test real API, but want to test a feature that used a API. So I should make mock data in the test code. I found `https://github.com/bblimke/webmock`.